# Clear data stored with drupal_static() and cache_set()

Tags: 7, caching

I have a custom module in Drupal 7 where I am caching data from REST calls using `drupal_static()` and `cache_set()`.

```
function _mymodule_call() {
  $data = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__);
  if ( ! isset($data) ) {
    if ($cache = cache_get(__FUNCTION__)) {
      $data = $cache->data;
    }
    else {
      $data = my_api_call();

      if ( is_object($lists) ) {
        // cache for one hour
        cache_set(__FUNCTION__, $data, 'cache', time() + 3600);
      }
    }
  }
  return $data;
}
```

I want to make an admin feature where we can specifically clear these cached values. I suppose the cache key would be `_mymodule_call`. How do I clear them from the cache?

Comment: I do not have the time to write a complete answer, but there is a good tutorial here: https://www.lullabot.com/articles/a-beginners-guide-to-caching-data-in-drupal-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a test script, and it turns out that in my code above, `_mymodule_call` is the `$cid`, because I created my cache in the `_mymodule_call` function like so: `cache_set(__FUNCTION__, $data, 'cache', time() + 3600);`.

Thanks to mpdonadio for noting that you have to specify the `$bin` argument when you use `cache_clear_all()`. In my case, since I wasn't specifying it in `cache_set()`, it defaults to `'cache'`.

Here's my script:

```
$> cat cache_test.php
<?php
// set the cache
cache_set('test_key', 'hello there ' . mt_rand(), 'cache');
$data = cache_get('test_key');
// display it
print_r($data);
// clear it
cache_clear_all('test_key', 'cache');
// retrieve it (should be empty)
$data = cache_get('test_key');
// display the emptied(?) cache
var_dump($data);
print_r($data);
```

And here's its output:

```
$> drush scr cache_test.php
stdClass Object
(
    [cid] => test_key
    [data] => hello there 1718114879
    [created] => 1482938803
    [expire] => 0
    [serialized] => 0
)
bool(false)
```

Answer (score 4):

The Drupal way is to have a `$reset` parameter to your function.  It would look something like:

```
function _mymodule_call($reset = FALSE) {
  if ($reset) {
    // do stuff
  }
  // ...
}
```

[`node_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load/7.x) is probably the best example of this.

In your specific case, you can pass the `$reset` parameter to `drupal_static()` or explicitly call [`drupal_static_reset()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static_reset/7.x).  For the cache backend, you need to think whether you want to just rework the logic and just do the `cache_set()` or explicitly call [`cache_clear_all($cid)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/7.x) (my guess is the former).

And remember, that `drupal_static()` is only effective when you need the value multiple times *during the same request*.  This does not persist between page loads (or any other HTTP request that get handled by Drupal).

Comment: `cache_clear_all($cid)` -- in my case, would that be `cache_clear_all('_mymodule_call')`?

Comment: @user1359 Looks like it would be `cache_set(__FUNCTION__, 'cache')`; the `$bin` needs to be specified when you use the `$cid`.  Check out the API page.